Coworker's curt rejection felt hurtful - am I overreacting?
I'm need some advice on a work situation that’s been bothering me:
We had a team meeting to discuss how we’re going to handle my coworker "Alice's" workload while she’s on leave. During the meeting, Alice, "Belinda" and our manager were talking about needing extra help, possibly hiring someone temporarily or redistributing tasks within the team. Alice was really stressing out that her work wouldn't get done in her absence and that Belinda might not be able to handle it. I offered to take on some of the work to ease Belinda’s already heavy load.
To my surprise, Alice flatly turned me down, saying I wasn’t familiar enough with some of the specific procedures. It's fine if she doesn't need my help, but what really threw me off was HOW she did it: very abruptly, with an expression on her face as if she had seen something very unpleasant, without any thanks for the offer, or even a discussion on how I might be able to get up to speed. When I asked what kind of skills/knowledge are needed to take over the extra work, Alice refused to give any concrete details, just saying over and over that "Seesaw knows NOTHING about the project". Her responses struck me as quite unprofessional, bordering on rude. I didn't insist after she shot me down, then Belinda jumped in and said that actually it would be useful if I'm there to help out, but she was also curtly shot down by Alice.
If I didn't want the help of a coworker, I'd say that I'll take stock of what needs to be done and get back to them if I need their help (a soft let down, so to speak). Or say that the work needs certain technical knowledge so I'm not sure they would fit but thanks anyway for offering to help. But the blunt dismissal that Alice gave was kind of hurtful, if I'm honest.
Am I overreacting to Alice's curt dismissal of my help? I gave her the benefit of the doubt, specially considering she's pregnant and maybe more stressed/anxious. At the same time, I do feel a bit hurt. I'll continue to be professional of course, but maybe dial it down to neutral and stiff politeness with her.
How would you handle this kind of situation, especially with these cliquey undertones affecting professional relationships?
Thanks!
PS: To be clear, I have no interest in the tasks and I have enough work to do. I only offered to help out after hearing their lengthy discussion during our meeting and because I think it's normal to help each other out as a team when needed.

Why does Alice have a say who replaces her?

Good question! She has the most knowledge about the technicalities of the project, so our manager probably thought she's the best judge of who can take on her tasks. He is also quite non-confrontational and prefers to delegate decisions like this.

@seesaw - So this individual probably has a pretty good grasp of what knowledge is required. Are you familiar with the procedures? Was this evaluation of your skills at all accurate? I have had coworkers who would cause me more work, to clean up after them, if they attempted to do my tasks. I would have a more tactful way of say “thanks no thanks” probably in private

@Donald - I have some experience but not as much as her, since she's the only one on this project. Further than that, I can't gauge the extent to which I can help because Alice refused to provide specifics when we were asking her about the tasks. To be clear, I'm perfectly ok if my help isn't needed. I was just a bit taken aback at her immediate dismissal, inflexibility and lack of gratitude. It was rude and also a bit humiliating as it was in front of other people. She didn't even address me directly but said to the room in general: "I'm uncomfortable with Seesaw helping because [reasons]".

Out of curiousity, have you worked on Alice's work load in the past?  The way you're phrasing the rejection here, it sounds like there has been a past experience that has soured their experience of getting help from you on this project. If you haven't, it could be worth asking if there's something in your experience that Alice knows of that is specifically the cause of concern (i.e. language convention conflicts, protocol level of malicious implementations etc.).

@AlexanderThe1st - no, we work on different projects. The meeting is to give manager an overview of all his projects. Re: past experience, all that comes to mind is an ex-coworker (Dana) who disliked me, made snarky comments to my face and gossip behind my back to others (Cara) that I'm aloof and arrogant. Since she and Alice shared an office, I'm pretty sure Dana undermined me to her as well. Dana left but Cara and Alice remained frosty. Belinda is new and has been warm and kind to me. I was cordial with Alice and Cara coz I dont want to create drama, but now it seems best to just peace out.

@seesaw: sorry but no sorry: you present yourself as somebody who wants to help people while in fact you seek pleasure in other people's failing, as you have put it so well in the comment on diligent workers's answer: "Watching from the sidelines as her work implodes is the perfect level of petty and I love it". So, what's the real motivation behind your question here?

You won the lottery. Now you don't have to get involved in helping to do her work during her leave. You can focus on your own work. You shouldn't let Alice take up so much time in your brain. She's not worth it. You're a quality person, she isn't. Don't get involved. Let her work implode and just watch from the sidelines.

Thanks for the kind words and putting the situation into perspective :) Watching from the sidelines as her work implodes is the perfect level of petty and I love it :D

You're welcome!!!

No. Not interested in the story. Alice clearly insulted OP. Why should he continue to care about her or her work? It's not petty, it's assertive.

@DiligentWorker25 I'm a girl, but yes thanks again :) I fail to see what Fe203's story has to do with this situation. I'm not the one refusing to cooperate with a team member here. If Alice's project suffers because she threw away help offered then it's on her. There is a way to decline help without damaging working relationships.

I'm sorry I called you a he. I agree with you. There's no reason for her reaction to your willingness to help. It seems like she's insecure. I would stay away just to keep your peace of mind. Other people can sort out her work.

Before we leap to judge, I'm conscious that we're only hearing one side of the story.  What might Alice's side sound like?

You offered to help and they rejected that offer.  Based on the manner of their rejection, I would never offer to or actually help those coworkers with anything going forward unless your boss specifically instructs you to do so.  Limit your interactions with this group to only what is absolutely necessary for you to do your own work going forward.

Thanks, that's how I plan to approach Alice and Cara going forward. It's just disappointing to see this mean girl behavior and I'm also amazed that people feel ok to talk rudely like this. Maybe I'm weird but I think about how to phrase what I'm going to say so that it comes across appropriately, and in a work environment you try to keep the atmosphere cordial at least. I'd never speak to someone like this and then carry on as if nothing happened. But yes, now I will just focus on my own work and not go near them unless I have to. Thanks!

yeah, a good response would be "well then I guess y'all will figure it out. Let me know if you need help in the future."

Was your coworker's rebuff witnessed by the manager him/herself?
Then I would expect that manager to have had a private word with “Alice" and communicated their disapproval of her uncalled for rude response. You wouldn't necessarily be informed, but sometimes word gets out if there has been follow-up.
In the meantime, always maintain civil communications with all your coworkers, do not complain or express your feelings of being slighted with anyone in the team,  it is none of their business anyway, and  wait patiently for the storm in the teacup to die down.

Yes, our manager was there. Afterwards he left and I was getting my stuff too when Belinda once again said it would be useful to have my help. Once again, Alice launched into "She knows NOTHING about the protocol", looking visibly flustered and repeated her rejection several times. I shrugged and told them to let me know if they need anything, then I left.
Our manager is supportive of me but very non-confrontational; not the type to call people out for stuff like this. I'll be cordial with Alice but I also wanted to know if I'm overreacting or is Alice really being unprofessional? :(

@seesaw what Alice said and how she behaved was an overreaction on her side, and I'd expect your manager to have had a quiet word with her. But if he doesn't like confrontation then you have to accept that and move on. For whatever reason Alice reacted the way she did, you did the right thing, and you have to shrug it off. Don't overthink it, focus on your work, and when Alice comes back to work pretend it never happened. But now you know her a little better, from now on just act civilly toward her.

So, you volunteered to help, but Alice said no, and put you down, and then later Belina again volunteered you (not herself!), giving Alice the opening to put you down again? You need to ask Belinda not to do this again.

@DimitriVulis Belinda's action to me reads more like trying to calm the waters and reassure OP that they could help out. I see no fault in her suggestion OP to help since OP suggested that already. All in all, she might be an ally if Alice indeed has a feud with OP, so souring the relationship with her seems like a bad reaction.

Indeed, Belinda has been really nice. She even came to me later and said she was surprised that Alice didn't want me to help out and that the way Alice handled it was not nice. I'm grateful that she stuck up for me and I'll support her if she wants it because she's truly a kind and positive person.
